# Auto login subdomain from main domain on single sites with different DB

Tags: database, login, subdomains, encryption

I would like to auto login to subdomain from main domain as well as from subdomain to main domain (if possible).

I was already able to do this by sending url with encoded params to own php login file but weak security and encryption php control for the url param would put perfomance load on server.

I think cookies are the right way to approach and know that it can be shared within domain network but the cookie setups I have seen in wp-config address using same DB - I have separate DB's. Note that I have ensured same users present in all DB's so both users and cookie info should be accessable.

Any way to use cookies in network but on different DB or at least some other way making this work? Also aware of some plugins with sync session cookie and IP but would like not to rely on plugins for this (at least not minor used plugins) which might also have other performance load features.

BR

Comment: It might be easier/more sustainable if you were able to combine the single installs into a single Multisite. Then once a user is logged in, they'd have access to any subsites (subdomains) they have privileges on.

Comment: Yes on this point a benefit but the sites are with different themes, plugins and some plugins not multisite - also like the db be separated. Bulk admin/updates can be handled easy anyway so besides this user login I prefer the setup og single sites - just not sure what I do on this one.

Comment: One option would be to use a Single Sign-On plugin, like Authorizer, with a CAS server or some other means of single authentication. That way once the user signs onto the external system, they are authenticated for all the sites that use this method of authentication.

Comment: Looked at this but seems as the users cannot use all typical social logins and would need to install device app and setup. Needs to be fast and quick signup/in.